# Is there a way represent a color as a single value?

Tags: opencv, colors

So I've got this stack of images (about 1000) and I've used CV2 and Python to find the predominant color in each one. Since it's OpenCV, I can get that color in a variety of formats, RGB, HSV, etc.

What I'm trying to find out (not being a computer vision or math whiz) is if there's a way to store that predominant color as a single value of some kind - for searching and sorting.

I know there's a formula using HSV to calculate the "distance" between one color and another, but that's a lot of math for what's really a silly little program.

Is there any kind of single value? Or does it "just not work that way"?

Thanks.

Comment: There are lots of ways of searching and sorting images - it just depends what you want to be able to do. Maybe you could clarify what sort of thing you plan to do?

Answer (score 1):

The way the color are described using OpenCV and other image software is not the same way that humans interpret color. Most people will interpret red and orange to be close to each other, and red and blue to be far from each other. Image software programs describe color using intensity, gradient, and wavelength.

When people consider color, most people are thinking of colors with saturation and values of 255. To find the distance between color, you can look at the difference between their HSV values.

[image: hues]

This is the code that I used to generate that gif:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
h = 0
while True:
    img = np.zeros((200,200,3), np.uint8)
    img[:,:,:] = h, 255, 255
    img = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_HSV2BGR)
    cv2.imshow('img', img)
    k = cv2.waitKey(1)
    if k == 27: break
    h += 1
    if h == 180: h = 0
```

Comment: In other news, my laptop died this morning. So this coding project has dropped dramatically in the priority list. Thanks for the answers so far. I'll be back... hopefully soon.

Comment: @Dito Sorry about your laptop, but don't let that stop you. It is very easy to use Python/OpenCV in Google Colab. Here is a tutorial to get you started: https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1RWGmqoEQdeyh5TssoGtsXsFk8hbLGtWp#scrollTo=5iE-OdEMoTWD